# web.config redirect "index.php" pattern to home page of domain

Tags: iis, web-config

I have a few bots crawling my sites for very old pages (when I used joomla as CMS), so every index.php/... now generates a 404 in log.
I'm trying to create a redirect rule in web.config so that all links that relate to index.php... will now be redirected to the root domain. There are 4 domains pointing to this site, so it needs to redirect to the proper domain.

As examples:

site1.com/index.php?something needs to redirect to site1.com

site2.com/index.php/alsosomething need to redirect to site2.com

I have URL Rewrite module in IIS, so I just need to create the rule, but I can't figure the patterns.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions at Joomla Stack Exchange.

Comment: It's not a joomla question. It's a win server now.